# iOS Keep Order of Async Queries

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

```
    - (void)loadItems {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [manager GET:@"someurl"
      parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
              [self reloadData];
          }

      } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
          NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
      }];
}

- (void)textFieldDidChange {
    [_filteredArray removeAllObjects];
    [self loadItems];
}
```

I am trying to implement instant search by making an API call every time a character changes. Since, the first few calls have less letters, they return more results, making the first few async calls finish slower than than the last few, meaning that if I type in `hello` quickly, I will end up getting the search results for `h` instead of the whole word since the last call to finish is the one for h. I need to keep the order of these calls, and make sure that the last query is not overwritten. I understand that I must use a queue structure. However doing something like this in `textFieldDidChange` doesn't seem to work:

```
dispatch_group_async(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
    [self loadItems];
});
dispatch_group_notify(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
    [self reloadData];
});
```

I think I need to use some sort of combination of `dispatch_group_enter(group);` and `dispatch_group_leave(group);`. However I still can't get the calls to stop overwriting the last call. I'm not sure if there is also a way to just cancel out all the other started calls with the last one, or if I have to wait for all of them to finish in order. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution. I just ended up using a counter that I pass into my `loadItems` function. While that counter updates, the async call still has its own value in it, so I just compare the two, and make sure to only `reloadData` if the async call's counter is equal to the latest one.

```
- (void)loadItems:(int)queryInt {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [manager GET:@"someurl"
      parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
              if (searchQueryCounter - 1 == queryInt) {
                  [self reloadDatawithAnimation];
              } else {
                  return;
              }
      } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
          NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
      }];
}

- (void)textFieldDidChange {
    [_filteredArray removeAllObjects];
    [self loadItems:searchQueryCounter];
    searchQueryCounter = searchQueryCounter + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might better address this by canceling the prior requests, not only preventing prior requests reporting results, but also ensuring that system resources are not consumed by requests that are no longer needed:

```
@interface ViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSOperation *previousOperation;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // no need to instantiate new request operation manager each time;
    // do it at some logical point of initialization (e.g. in `viewDidLoad`
    // for view controllers, etc.).

    self.manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [self.manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
}

- (void)loadItems {
    [self.previousOperation cancel];
    typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;  // probably should use weakSelf pattern, too
    NSOperation *operation = [self.manager GET:@"someurl" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [weakSelf reloadData];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if ([error.domain isEqualToString:NSURLErrorDomain] && [error code] != NSURLErrorCancelled) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }
    }];
    self.previousOperation = operation;
}

- (void)textFieldDidChange {
    [_filteredArray removeAllObjects];
    [self loadItems];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually worked on a very similar problem last week and came up with an approach you might find useful.

I submit each request using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` with a slight delay (I've been experimenting with values ranging from 0.5 to 1.0 seconds. Somewhere from .66 to .75 seems like a good compromise value.)

With each new request, I cancel the previous pending performSelector call. That way nothing gets sent until the user stops typing for a short period of time. It's not perfect, but it reduces the amount of useless queries for word fragments. The code looks something like this:

```
static NSString *methodWord = nil;
[[self class] cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget: self
                                             selector: @selector(handleWordEntered:)
                                               object: methodWord];
methodWord = word;
[self performSelector: @selector(handleWordEntered:)
           withObject: methodWord
           afterDelay: .667];
```

The method `handleWordEntered:` actually sends the request to the server.

If the user types a letter, then another letter in less than 2/3 second, the previous pending request is cancelled and a new request is set to fire 2/3 of a second later. As long as the user keeps typing letters every 2/3 second, nothing is sent. As soon as the user pauses more than 2/3 second, a request is sent. Once the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` fires it can't be cancelled any more, so that request goes to the network and the reply is parsed.